# ¿Por qué mi modal no funciona cuando genero un elemento con jQuery?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Al crear un botón que llame el modal, funciona correctamente:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal">Modal</a>
```

Pero al generar un elemento con jquery, el modal deja de funcionar

```
$.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(usuariosReq){
            $(usuariosReq).each(function(key, value){
                tablaDatos.append("<tr><th>"+value.id+"</th><td>"+value.nombre+"</td><td>"+value.apellido+"</td><td>"+value.correo+"</td><td><div class='btn-group'><a class='btn btn-small btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger' data-target='#modal'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>  Ver</a><a href='{{URL::route('usuario.edit', "+value.id+")}}' class='btn btn-small btn-rounded green'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>  Editar</a><a class='btn btn-small btn-rounded red' onclick='eliminar("+value.id+")'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>  Eliminar</a></div></td></tr>");
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Debes llamarlo por medio de on() , pues tu botón generado no está en el DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocupa la delegación de eventos a través de  `.on()` en vez de utilizar el data attributes para esos enlaces creados dinamicamente. Por ejemplo si tienes un `table` como elemente fijo y solo le insertas elementos `tr` debes hacer el bind del evento click a través del `table`. De esta manera el elemento `table`.

Supongamos que al enlace le ponemos la clase `.trigger-edit-modal` y el `table` posee el id `users-table`, entonces sería algo así:

```
$('#users-table').on('click', '.trigger-edit-modal', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var modalId = $this.attr('href'); // o $this.data('target');

    $(modalId).modal('show');
});
```

Esto además aumentará el rendimiento, ya que solo existirá un solo handler para ese evento ;). En la documentación hay más info sobre la delegación de eventos, [jQuery api: .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En teoría debería funcionar así

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    type: "GET",
    success: function(usuariosReq) {
        $.each(usuariosReq, function (key, value) {
            tablaDatos.append("<tr><th>"+value.id+"</th><td>"+value.nombre+"</td><td>"+value.apellido+"</td><td>"+value.correo+"</td><td><div class='btn-group'><a class='btn btn-small btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger' data-target='#modal'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>  Ver</a><a href='{{URL::route('usuario.edit', "+value.id+")}}' class='btn btn-small btn-rounded green'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>  Editar</a><a class='btn btn-small btn-rounded red' onclick='eliminar("+value.id+")'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>  Eliminar</a></div></td></tr>");
        });
        $("#id_modal_markup").modal('show');
    }
});
```

Sería bueno ver el html de como esta construido el modal. También se podría dar que el modal se muestre antes de que el html se termine de construir así que podría utilizar promesas